# matrix multiplication inner dimensions should match error

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have this doubt in matrix multiplication, if i multiply a matrix A1 of [2 * 3] dimension and matrix A2 of dimension [4 * 5] then the matlab will through the error inner dimensions should match. Now I started thinking why should inner dimension should match? Who designed this? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: uh... that's the way matrix multiplication works. math designed it. the reason is that nothing else would work.

Comment: no offense, any book in basic matrix algebra will give you answer :)

Comment: yes correct but any physical significance for such kind of definition. In any case I will accept it and proceed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product) is tedious but really precise. But I think it's the need for linear combinations.

Say we have matrices A (5 by 3) and B (3 by 4) and multiplication C = A * B. A contains 5 row vectors and B contains 4 column vectors. The vectors in B are 4 physical vectors existing in the vector space (R3 as the simplest case) to which B belongs.

Now we want to linearly combine these 4 vectors in 5 different ways to generate 5 new vectors in the same space. We can do either in the following: 1) write the 5 summation equations separately with linear weights as multiplicative coefficients in front of each vector; or 2) define matrix multiplication. It makes life easier, just like 5*5 is a simpler way to express 5+5+5+5+5